# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: networkRequest

Tags: typescript, react-native

When I used scrollable-tabview in import refresh functinality then it will raised one error like this.

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: networkRequest

```
_onRefresh = (callback) => {
    networkRequest().then(response => callback(response))    
  } 

render() {
      return <ScrollableTabView
        refreshControlStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
        pullToRefresh={this._onRefresh}
      >
        <ScrollView tabLabel="Pending" >
          <View>
            <Text>Pending</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView tabLabel="Upcoming" >
          <View>
            <Text>Upcoming</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView tabLabel="Completed" >
          <View>
            <Text>Completed</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </ScrollableTabView>
    }
  }
```

[[image: When I scroll activity for refresh that time generate error]

[image: For this refresh indicator for use network request]

Comment: There is nothing like `networkRequest` in `react-native`.

Comment: Yeah I did removed but it will show me referenceError: Can't find variable: networkRequest

Comment: What is an problem on to this code. help to solve my problem

Comment: Why do you wanna use `networkRequest`?

Comment: for get network data when data was not loaded perfectly or get updated data.

Comment: There is nothing like `networkRequest` in React Native iirc. Use `fetch`. https://css-tricks.com/using-data-in-react-with-the-fetch-api-and-axios/